# Relay Style pagination in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo, apollo-client

How does relay-style pagination works in react like it worked for one query and not working for another. Do I need to change something in it? In the old query, fetchmore function fetched the new products and display them on the page in addition to the old ones. However, fetchmore gets the data for the new query but doesn't update it on the screen and displays the old data on the screen.

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
            products: relayStylePagination()
     }
   }
});
```

New query:

```
const QUERY = gql`
  query Fetch($handle: String!, $after: String, $first: Int, $before: String) {
    collectionByHandle(handle: $handle) {
      id
      description
      products(first: $first, after: $after, before: $before) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            description
            priceRange {
              minVariantPrice {
                amount
                currencyCode
              }
            }
            updatedAt
            productType
            title
            images(first: 1) {
              edges {
                node {
                  transformedSrc(maxWidth: 300)
                }
              }
            }
          }
          cursor
        }
        pageInfo {
          hasNextPage
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Old query:

```
const QUERY = gql`
  query productFetch($first: Int, $after: String, $query: String) {
    products(first: $first, after: $after, query: $query) {
      edges {
        node {
          priceRange {
            minVariantPrice {
              amount
              currencyCode
            }
          }
          updatedAt
          productType
          title
          images(first: 1) {
            edges {
              node {
                transformedSrc(maxWidth: 300)
              }
            }
          }
        }
        cursor
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/cursor-based/#relay-style-cursor-pagination

Comment: @xadm Yes I have read the documentation but nothing seems to make this query working

Comment: @Huma Were you able to fix this. I've the same problem.